# Pandas apply on DF returns "No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'">

Tags: python, pandas

```
df[['col - 1','col 2','col 3','col 4','col 5','col 6']].apply(aFunction,axis=1)
```

returns there error:

> No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

I've tried

```
df[['col - 1','col 2','col 3','col 4','col 5','col 6']].apply(lambda row:aFunction(row),axis=1)
```

And I get the same thing

**Further explorations:**

If I use print like so:

```
df[['col - 1','col 2','col 3','col 4','col 5','col 6']].apply(lambda row:print(row),axis=1)
```

Pandas Series for each row will be printed out

If I place a print function in "aFunction" that prints out the return values, the expected output will be printed.

Comment: Can you share the contents of `aFunction` it seems that somewhere in `aFunction` that you're trying to use a method with `axis=1` on a `Series`

Comment: @CameronRiddell Yes, that's the solution... thank you